# Is there a way to speed up audio processing (amix and adelay) in FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm using, in android application, many `ffmpeg` amix and adelay filter commands over very small mp3 files (not longer than 3 seconds). 
Unfortunately each adelay or amix command takes between 2 and 4 seconds to execute, which is a lot considering that I should run the same operation for a lot of files.
Here are two example of commands I'm running:

amix:

```
[-i, input1.mp3, -i, input2.mp3, -filter_complex, amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm=f=100[aout], -map, [aout], -ac, 2, -c:a, libmp3lame, -q:a, 4, output.mp3]
```

adelay:

```
[-i, input3.mp3, -filter_complex, [0:a]adelay=1|1, -c:a, libmp3lame, output1.mp3]
```

I know in video there is an option (-preset ultrafast) to make the execution faster, is there a way to do the same for audio?

Answer (score 1):

If you want faster processing do not use `libmp3lame` encoder, instead use some faster encoder like `flac`.
Filters you mentioned are already very optimized so they are certainly not reason for performance issues you are experiencing.